# Netsh в TMemo

Tags: delphi, cmd, netsh

Всем доброго [утра:дня:вечера:ночи]  Набросал программку на Delphi. Функционал: вкл\выкл сетевых подкл. Ренэйм сетевых подкл. Всё срабатывает, НО!  Есть одно но, ПО при выполнении команды netsh через процедуру, которая проводит команды командного процессора через TMemo, просто виснет намертво. В ОЗУ остаётся висеть netsh.exe.  Пример кода выполнения netsh:

```
RunDosInMemo('netsh interface set interface name="'+PChar(Edit2.Text)+'"newname="'+PChar(Edit3.Text)+'"', Memo1);   RunDosInMemo('exit', Memo1);
```

Как это победить?

Comment: Тут [CreateProcess using netsh hangs/freezes the application (Delphi)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712386/createprocess-using-netsh-hangs-freezes-the-application-delphi) были?

Answer (score 1):

Используй потоки, например класс **TThread**